# Djongo - Cannot put my own models in documents

Tags: django, mongodb, djongo

I have the following Python code that I am trying to migrate from mongonaut to the new way of interfacing Django with MongoDB, the djongo package:

```
# CharField for English and Japanese text
class LocalizedCharField(models.Model):
EN = models.CharField()
JP = models.CharField()

class Meta:
    abstract = False

# Details for a character
class CharacterInfo(models.Model):
charName = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False, null=False)
displayName =  models.EmbeddedField(model_container=LocalizedCharField)
nationality = models.EmbeddedField(model_container=LocalizedCharField)
game = models.EmbeddedField(model_container=LocalizedCharField)
system = models.EmbeddedField(model_container=LocalizedCharField)
voice = models.EmbeddedField(model_container=LocalizedCharField)
graphic = models.EmbeddedField(model_container=LocalizedCharField)
introduction = models.EmbeddedField(model_container=LocalizedCharField)
defaultPalIndices = models.CharField(max_length=128)
groove = models.JSONField(blank=True, null=True)
config = models.JSONField()
moves = models.JSONField()
charConfig = models.JSONField()

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.charName

class Meta(object):
    verbose_name = "Character"
    verbose_name_plural = "Characters"

# Main page post
class Post(models.Model):
title = models.EmbeddedField(model_container=LocalizedCharField)
date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
content = models.EmbeddedField(model_container=LocalizedCharField)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title["EN"]
```

However, I get the following error when I try to debug my server:

```
['Field "lawn.LocalizedCharField.id" of model container:"<class \'lawn.models.LocalizedCharField\'>" cannot be of type "<class \'django.db.models.fields.AutoField\'>"']
```

And it points to the line where `displayName` is as the culprit, meaning I for some reason can't embed my own field types in other models? What do I have to do to make this work? As said before, up until this point, I was using an outdated custom build of Mongonaut where this worked fine, so I'm unsure what djongo wants.

Comment: This is not how one handles localization/internationalization: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

Comment: `LocalizedCharField ` is twice in your file.

Comment: @ShreeyanshJain Minute late, I realized that

Comment: After further testing, I still have the issue even with the duplicate class removed